# get dominant color from URL image react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to retrieve the dominant color from an online image in a react-native project initialized with expo. I have tried every single color grab library and all of them either return an unfulfilled promise or something like this [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMck4.png) . Here is an example of how I would need it to work in the project. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
import ImageColors from 'react-native-image-colors'

const url = `https://website.com/image.png`

export default function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchColors = async () => {
            const result = await ImageColors.getColors(url, {
                fallback: '#000000',
                quality: 'low',
            })

            switch (result.platform) {
                case 'android':
                    console.log(result)
                case 'web':
                    console.log(result)
                    break
                case 'ios':
                    console.log(result)
                    break
                default:
                    throw new Error('Unexpected platform')
            }

        }

        fetchColors()

    }, [])

    const handleClick = () => {

        //need to trigger color search here..

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable expo ready to use the react-native-image-colors we have to set up expo-dev-client.

So we have to install expo-dev-client and follow the official documentation.

[Add Support for expo-dev-client](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/)

Comment: Hi, can you give more info about react-native-image-colors